# Wordpress - s2member plugin : membership to fixed date

Tags: wordpress, plugins, membership

I'm integrating s2member as membership plugin to an existing wordpress site.
It is easy to generate the paypal button so the user is subscribing, for exemple, for one year of membership.
Our membership will effectively be valid for one year, but from a fixed date to another fixed date.
Basically, the membership must be valid from 1st of june (2011) to may 31 (2012). The user may have from may 15 to june 15 to subscribe, but we want the membership to end on may 31, whatever is the date the membership is purchased.
Is it possible?
Thanks ;)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible.  From the [documentation](http://www.primothemes.com/readme/914/):

> s2Member uses its built-in Auto-EOT System. EOT = End Of Term. Whenever you generate a PayPal® Button with s2Member, you'll configure a length for the Subscription. Depending on the type of Subscription you choose ( recurring, non-recurring, lifetime, or fixed-term ); s2Member will either use PayPal's IPN/subscr_payment,subscr_cancel,subscr_eot notices, or it will set an Automatic EOT Time, which is processed automatically by s2Member via WP_Cron. For each Member, you can also override the EOT Time, by forcing a specific expiration date. To manually adjust the EOT Time for a specific Member, go to: WordPress® -> Users, and click the Edit link next the Member you want to work on.

That said, there is likely a date field in an s2Member table that you can override with a default value of May 31.  Granted, additional constraints will need to be enforced programmatically to account for the rest of your membership logic.  Example:

```
if ( date() >=  $signupStartDate and date() <= $signupEndDate ) {
     processForm();
} else {
     die ( "You cannot sign up right now.  Try again on " . $signupStartDate . "." );
}
```

Comment: It might also be worthwhile to play around with line 116 of [this puppy](http://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/s2member/tags/110926/includes/classes/auto-eots.inc.php) on your sandbox first, of course!